# How can I print an error's message in Actix-Web without panicking?

Tags: rust, rust-actix

I'm trying to understand the error handling from one of the [examples](https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/master/simple-auth-server/src/errors.rs) from the Actix repo. It uses the `failure` crate to handle errors. Here's a relevant piece of code:

```
#[derive(Fail, Debug)]
pub enum ServiceError {
    #[fail(display = "Internal Server Error: {}", _0)]
    InternalServerError(String),

    #[fail(display = "BadRequest: {}", _0)]
    BadRequest(String),

    #[fail(display = "Unauthorized")]
    Unauthorized,
}

impl ResponseError for ServiceError {
    fn error_response(&self) -> HttpResponse {
        match *self {
            ServiceError::InternalServerError { .. } => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().json("Internal Server Error, Please try later"),
            ServiceError::BadRequest(ref message) => HttpResponse::BadRequest().json(message)
        }
    }
}

impl From<ParseError> for ServiceError {
    fn from(_: ParseError) -> ServiceError {
        ServiceError::BadRequest("Invalid UUID".into())
    }
}
```

If my handler returns a `ServiceError` the code doesn't panic, it will render an `HttpResponse` (see `error_response()`). Because of this, I won't be able to see a `Fail` message (`#[fail(display`...) in my terminal.

Is there any nice built-in way to display it in my logs other than by adding `println!` to `error_response`? I believe it totally makes sense to display the exact error rather than generic `InternalServerError`: i.e., *NetworkError/ParseError*.

If not, what is the reason it was designed without the ability to see the exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actix-Web renders errors to [`log::error!`](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.6/log/macro.error.html). Try to start your example with `RUST_LOG=actix_web=debug`

Comment: Could you specify the former part of your answer?

Comment: @JamesLarkin `actix` logs all errors using the `log` crate. Depending on the [logger your program uses](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.6/log/index.html#available-logging-implementations), some messages will be filtered out. Nikolay assumes you are using [`env_logger`](https://docs.rs/env_logger/*/env_logger/) or something compatible, which allows to change the filter while starting the program to include those error messages.